# Cannot connect to Apache Kafka with Confluent.Kafka hosted on IBM

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ibm-eventstreams

I am trying to connect to IBM's managed Apache Kafka solution. This is what IBM states in its documentation to connect
`bootstrap.servers=broker-2-****.kafka.svc03.us-***.cloud.ibm.com:9093,
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="token" password="<api_key>";,
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN,
security.protocol=SASL_SSL,ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2`

And this is how i have configured in code

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
       {
           BootstrapServers = "broker-****.kafka.svc03.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.*,****.kafka.****.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.***",
           SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
           Debug = "broker,security,protocol",
           EnableSslCertificateVerification = false,
           SocketTimeoutMs = 5000,
           SaslUsername = "token",
           SaslPassword = "******",
           SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl
       };
```

However i couldn't get to set the ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2 in c# code. Not sure if that is reason for the issue. Anyways Here is the error i get. [Error Logs Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayasurya-jeyakodi/Temp/master/Logs)

I tried to understand the logs and i suspect something with Versioning, cannot figure out the exact issue.

I am running on:

1. Dotnet core 3.1
2. Confluent.Kafka(1.4.0). Let me know if you need more details